# Microsoft Bot Framework: How to determine if this 1:1 chat is with bot and not with other users or apps?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to check if there is any way to know who is part of a conversation before we can mark the as private or bot channel?

I am marking the conversation as private using the following logic:
`turnContext.getActivity().getConversation().isGroup()`.

Also, I have another question, I am completely new to this bot development and microsoft bot development/SDK in general. How to get started with all these things. I am developing the bot in Java. I am don't find the documentation good enough and also there are not enough examples of the same in java online.

Comment: Glad you'r using Microsoft Bot Framework SDK. ☺️

Comment: Quick heads up, JAVA and Python SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending in November 2023. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-java#readme:~:text=The%20Bot%20Framework,Virtual%20Agents.

Comment: Check out this [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples) repository where you can find different bot samples made by the developers.

Comment: Also sharing this [Bot Builder Community](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity) Repository where it contains a collection of repos led by the community, containing extensions, including middleware, dialogs, recognizers and more for the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK.

Comment: Could you please clarify that you want to get the conversation IDs between user and app?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT by app you mean bot right? I want to get conversation Ids b/w the user and the app(bot).

Comment: @RamFattah Could you please tell me any quick way to get started on these things(development around teams and bot development)? Any source which has simple explanations of all these things. I don't exactly know what all these entities(classes) inside the bot framework actually mean? I don't know what is tenantId, objectId etc all these things. How to learn about all this stuff?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Actually I want to know who is part of a conversation before we can mark the as private or bot channel? That is I want to know if chat is with bot and not other user or apps.

Comment: @sv2311, sharing this [Teams Auth Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) that has been created using Bot Framework, it shows how to get started with authentication in a bot for Microsoft Teams. Step by step Add authentication to your Teams bot documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use below api to get the chat IDs between user and app.

```
GET /users/{user-id | user-principal-name}/teamwork/installedApps/{app-installation-id}/chat
```

The following is an example of the response.

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats/$entity",
   "id":"19:0de69e5e-2da8-4cf2-821f-5e6585b2c65b_f32b83bb-4fc8-4db7-b7f5-76cdbbb8aa1c@unq.gbl.spaces"
}
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userscopeteamsappinstallation-get-chat?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http